# How to call function defined inside a class?

Tags: python, function, class

How to call setValues function outside the class?

Class is defined as below:

```
class CallbackDataBlock(ModbusSparseDataBlock):

   def setValues(self, address, value):
       super(CallbackDataBlock, self).setValues(address, value)
       self.queue.put((self.devices.get(address, None), value))
```

Comment: That function is a method.  Create an instance of the class, say `c`, then call it like `c.setValues(...)`

Answer (score 4):

if you have an object (let's call it `my_object`) of class `CallbackDataBlock` you should be able to call it like this:

```
my_object = CallbackDataBlock()
my_object.setValues(myaddress, myvalue)
```

just make sure you put in correct address and value in the arguments.